# Data formatting in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have data in the following format

```
Wed Nov 13 21:32:22 GMT 2013
Unique  1011266
back    471693  46.6438%
edge    82093   8.1178%
Thu Nov 14 13:17:02 GMT 2013
Unique  1030845
back    479623  46.5271%
edge    91870   8.9121%
Fri Nov 15 13:17:01 GMT 2013
Unique  1012254
back    455858  45.0339%
edge    69738   6.8893%
Sat Nov 16 13:17:01 GMT 2013
Unique  1030938
back    473239  45.9037%
edge    107645  10.4414%
Sun Nov 17 13:17:01 GMT 2013
Unique  1012122
back    486244  48.0420%
edge    131616  13.0039%
Mon Nov 18 13:17:01 GMT 2013
Unique  1090236
back    489005  44.8531%
edge    118735  10.8907%
Tue Nov 19 13:17:01 GMT 2013
Unique  1054120
back    477180  45.2680%
edge    89535   8.4938%
```

I was thinking of plotting this using ggplot as a time series i.e plot date vs edge and date vs back. The value of back and edge in each row is its value and percentage but am unable to transpose it into a column format and hence into a data frame . Any help on this would be great .....

Desired output wanted is:

```
Date       unique  back   edge
2013-11-13 1011266 471693 82093
2013-11-14 1030845 479623 91870
```

Comment: Try `readLines`, `grep`, and `strsplit` to parse each type of line into a column

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `read.fwf` here:

```
dat <- read.fwf(file='file.txt', 
         width=list(28,c(6,-2,7),c(4,-4,6,-2,8),c(4,-4,5,-2,7)))
```

Basically, you just have to specify the `widths` argument. When multiple lines constitute one case, this is a list, where each element corresponds to the widths of the fields in each row. There are four rows per record, so you have a list of four vectors. Negative numbers are used for spaces between fields.

Here's the result:

```
> dat
                            V1     V2      V3   V4     V5       V6   V7    V8       V9
1 Wed Nov 13 21:32:22 GMT 2013 Unique 1011266 back 471693 46.6438% edge 82093  8.1178%
2 Thu Nov 14 13:17:02 GMT 2013 Unique 1030845 back 479623 46.5271% edge 91870  8.9121%
3 Fri Nov 15 13:17:01 GMT 2013 Unique 1012254 back 455858 45.0339% edge 69738  6.8893%
4 Sat Nov 16 13:17:01 GMT 2013 Unique 1030938 back 473239 45.9037% edge 10764  10.4414
5 Sun Nov 17 13:17:01 GMT 2013 Unique 1012122 back 486244 48.0420% edge 13161  13.0039
6 Mon Nov 18 13:17:01 GMT 2013 Unique 1090236 back 489005 44.8531% edge 11873  10.8907
7 Tue Nov 19 13:17:01 GMT 2013 Unique 1054120 back 477180 45.2680% edge 89535  8.4938%
```

I imagine you might want to transform this afterwards and specify names:

```
setNames(dat[,c(1,3,5,6,8,9)], 
         c('Date','Unique','back','backpercent','edge','edgepercent'))
```

You could also specify different `widths` initially to just skip the variable labels (unique, edge, back, etc.):

```
dat <- read.fwf(file='file.txt', 
         width=list(28,c(-8,7),c(-8,6,-2,8),c(-8,5,-2,9)),
         col.names=c('Date','Unique','back','backpercent','edge','edgepercent'))
dat
                          Date  Unique   back backpercent  edge edgepercent
1 Wed Nov 13 21:32:22 GMT 2013 1011266 471693    46.6438% 82093     8.1178%
2 Thu Nov 14 13:17:02 GMT 2013 1030845 479623    46.5271% 91870     8.9121%
3 Fri Nov 15 13:17:01 GMT 2013 1012254 455858    45.0339% 69738     6.8893%
4 Sat Nov 16 13:17:01 GMT 2013 1030938 473239    45.9037% 10764    10.4414%
5 Sun Nov 17 13:17:01 GMT 2013 1012122 486244    48.0420% 13161    13.0039%
6 Mon Nov 18 13:17:01 GMT 2013 1090236 489005    44.8531% 11873    10.8907%
7 Tue Nov 19 13:17:01 GMT 2013 1054120 477180    45.2680% 89535     8.4938%
```

You can then easily convert the `Date` column to POSIXct and do whatever you want with it:

```
as.POSIXct(as.character(dat$Date), format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S GMT %Y', tz='GMT')
```

Comment: thanks a lot .... for the explanation.. though my dumb head is still trying to understand the width part of read.fwf ....

Comment: @user3006691 Coming up with the values for `widths` basically just involves counting the number of columns allocated to each value in each row. Pretty tedious stuff, but it's the best solution with these kind of data files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what format your data are in, but let's say it's some kind of text file:

```
cat('Wed Nov 13 21:32:22 GMT 2013
Unique  1011266
back    471693  46.6438%
edge    82093   8.1178%
Thu Nov 14 13:17:02 GMT 2013
Unique  1030845
back    479623  46.5271%
edge    91870   8.9121%
Fri Nov 15 13:17:01 GMT 2013
Unique  1012254
back    455858  45.0339%
edge    69738   6.8893%
Sat Nov 16 13:17:01 GMT 2013
Unique  1030938
back    473239  45.9037%
edge    107645  10.4414%
Sun Nov 17 13:17:01 GMT 2013
Unique  1012122
back    486244  48.0420%
edge    131616  13.0039%
Mon Nov 18 13:17:01 GMT 2013
Unique  1090236
back    489005  44.8531%
edge    118735  10.8907%
Tue Nov 19 13:17:01 GMT 2013
Unique  1054120
back    477180  45.2680%
edge    89535   8.4938%\n', file='temp.txt')

raw <- readLines('temp.txt')

unique <- sapply(grep('Unique',raw,value=T),function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,' '))[3] )
back <- sapply(grep('back',raw,value=T),function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,' '))[5] )
edge <- sapply(grep('edge',raw,value=T),function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,' '))[5] )
dates <- as.POSIXct(sapply(grep('GMT',raw,value=T),function(x) 
                   as.POSIXct(strptime(gsub('GMT','',x),'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))),origin=origin)

# now make a data frame
dat <- data.frame(unique,back,edge,dates, row.names=NULL)

   dat
#    unique   back   edge               dates
# 1 1011266 471693  82093 2013-11-13 21:32:22
# 2 1030845 479623  91870 2013-11-14 13:17:02
# 3 1012254 455858  69738 2013-11-15 13:17:01
# 4 1030938 473239 107645 2013-11-16 13:17:01
# 5 1012122 486244 131616 2013-11-17 13:17:01
# 6 1090236 489005 118735 2013-11-18 13:17:01
# 7 1054120 477180  89535 2013-11-19 13:17:01

# now plot
ggplot(dat,aes(x=dates,y=edge)) + geom_point() + scale_x_datetime() + theme_bw()
ggplot(dat,aes(x=dates,y=back)) + geom_point() + scale_x_datetime() + theme_bw()
```

Comment: thanks @Gary Weissman ... this kinda works but I'm not sure how to cbind the data in a Posixct/posixlt format .. I edited my post showing the desired output .....

Comment: @user3006691 updated with data frame including POSIXct format

Comment: Hmmm, agree `read.fwf` is cleaner than all the `apply` and `strsplit`